# Input for LSTM using one hot encoding

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Time series forecasting: My data contains fo categorical values and to predict the next value. The categorical values are converted into one hot encode values using keras.

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Shape of the encoded values is

```
(824,8734)
```

Data contains of 1 sample with 824 time steps to predict the next time step.

```
n_steps=3
n_features=1
```

What is the input shape for the LSTM?

```
I tried
X.shape = (824, 8734, 3, 1)
y.shape=(824,8734)
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, verbose=0)


ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Comment: Try: `X = np.squeeze(X)` before `model.fit`

Comment: In addition, you can try n_steps=4 instead of removing the extra X dimension

Comment: Could you detail your input and output a bit more? What I understood is that you want to predict the next datapoint based on the past 3, and each datapoint has 8734 features. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlCorreia :  No, I have 824 time steps for 1 user with 1 feature(Location point). The location point is one hot encoded. So the size of array is changed from (824,1) to (824,8734). Based on this i need to predict the next location point using LSTM

Comment: So you do have 8734 features. The LSTM is transparent to the fact that it came from a single categorical variable and will see it as 8743 features. I suspect you're thinking of the problem in the wrong way though. See, to predict the next location, you need to train the model to predict locations you do know first. For that, you usually split the data into smaller sequences and use ``n_steps`` datapoints to predict the next one. You can see [this tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/time-series-analysis-with-lstm-using-pythons-keras-library/) for an example.